# Visual studio skipping code mfc C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to compile a simple function on button click

```
std::string file_name((LPCTSTR)m_file_name);


    file_name = "D:\\test_image.bmp";

    int width = 0;
    _width_glo = 0;
    _height_glo = 0;

    Mat image_inp;
    image_inp = imread(file_name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    width = image_inp.cols;
    TRACE("trace width : %d\r\n", width);

    _width_glo = image_inp.cols;
    _height_glo = image_inp.rows;

    BYTE *inp_value_buf = change_to_BYTE(image_inp);

    if(m_data_type_selected == BMP_value)
    {
        Reverse_top_bottom(inp_value_buf);
    }
```

But visual studio is skipping the line

```
int width = 0;
width = image_inp.cols;
```

and is not considering width as a variable while running also sending in junk values inside of `_width_glo` and _`height_glo`

Any  idea why is the code behaving like this ? thank you.

Comment: First, what does "skipping the line" mean? Second, have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: And what does "not considering width as a variable while running" mean? (BTW: you should check that the image loaded successfully before you attempt to do anything with it.)

Comment: yes the image is loaded probably and by not considering i meant it is not even allocating memory for that variable and putting junk values in the variables after it.

Comment: sorry for previous one.. i tried debugging it again after clearing cache and its running good while on debugging but when i try to run the release build it gives me the same problem

Comment: don't try to debug release builds. (you'll only see junk)

Comment: There is some ability to debug RelWithDebInfo configurations however due to optimizations it is not easy. At times I have created unoptimized release builds to reduce some of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compiled with release/optimization flags, most likely TRACE has no implementation, so `width` variable is simply removed by the compiler because it is not used at all.

Junk values inside of `_width_glo` and `_height_glo` are most likely not-initialized attributes of Mat's object `image_inp`. Note that uninitialized variables behaviour is undefined and often differs between Debug and Release (depending of the compiler, some may automatically initialize variables with zeros in some cases, but not in others).

Comment: thanks. Does that means that even if there are values for Mat object the release build can still show none value or junk for the variable i am assigning the value too ?

Comment: sorry.. selecting Paul's answer as his was the first one. Thank you again.

Comment: You should select the best, not the first one ;-), my post answers the question you asked in comment to Paul...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to debug Release build you may see that current statement arrow jumps several lines forward and even backward sometimes. You may also see incorrect values of variables. This is because optimizations that are usually turned on for Release builds.

Comment: Thank you. Does that means that even if there are values for Mat object the release build can still show none value or junk for the variable i am assigning the value too ?

Comment: The debugger may show junk or may not display the value at all (say there is no such known variable). That does not mean the value is incorrect (though it may be incorrect because of bugs in the code). Use logs/console output/debugger output to find out what are the real values. PS: Accept the answer that is most useful to you, not the first one, I'm not here for extra +15 rep ;)